# not able to query fields retrived by globalDescrible

Tags: apex, schema

I have retrieved all the fields from contact using Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
but when I try to perform query on retrieved field I get below error:

> Invalid field Contact.EmailBouncedDate for Contact

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Please share your code to help u better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the reason you cannot see this field, in general you should check if the field is accessible before adding it to your query.

```
for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap().values())
{
    if (field.getDescribe().isAccessible()
    {
        // can be added to query
    }
}
```

Note also that the development team intentionally did not build out `SELECT *` functionality. You should be cautious if you do so yourself.